# Apply new configuration to devstack from local.conf

Tags: openstack, devstack

If I set a couple of settings in my local.conf file in the /devstack folder for example:

```
ADMIN_PASSWORD=supersecret  
DATABASE_PASSWORD=iheartdatabases  
RABBIT_PASSWORD=flopsymopsy  
SERVICE_PASSWORD=iheartksl
```

and then run

```
./stack.sh
```

but then later want to append this file with some network configurations for example:

```
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.1.224/27  
FIXED_RANGE=10.11.12.0/24  
FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE=256  
FLAT_INTERFACE=eth0
```

will those new setting be applied to the cloud when I run `./unstack.sh` and then `./stack.sh`?

Answer (score 3):

unstack script stops all your cloud environment

stack script will reconfigure and build cloud from scratch.

If you have problems there is clean.sh script, that destroys every thing that was created.

In your case enough:

```
./unstack.sh && ./stack.sh
```